# Does a getColorBoundsRect() equivalent exist in javascript?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, html, canvas

just wanted to know if anybody has already done this in Javascript or if I have to do it myself - if latter: How would I do it? (not asking for a piece of code, only curious which approach you would use)

Comment: You should probably describe what you want to do here instead of just linking to some external site. Your question will become impossible to understand should that site change its URL or go offline.

Comment: one doesn't _need_ this link - I thought it would be nice to point out what I need it for, but I can remove it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a better solution. It is not necessary to iterate through **all** the pixels, only through the ones outside the bounding box. Think of it this way, if you wanted to do the same thing in 1D: finding the first and last position of a value in an array, would you walk through the entire array? It would be better to walk through from the start till you find the first value, then walk from the *end* till you find the last value. The following code does the same for 2D. I haven't tested it thoroughly (either for correctness or speed), but it seems to work, and common sense say it's faster.

```
BitmapData.prototype.getColorBoundsRect = function(mask, color, findColor, rect){
    findColor = typeof findColor !== 'undefined' ? findColor : true;
    rect = typeof rect !== 'undefined' ? rect : new module.Rect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);

    var l = rect.w - 1;
    var r = 0;
    var t = rect.h - 1;
    var b = 0;

    var data = this.context.getImageData(rect.x, rect.y, rect.w, rect.h).data;

    // Scan from top to first pixel.
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4){
        var val = module.RGBToHex({r:data[i], g:data[i+1], b:data[i+2], a:data[i+3]});
        // console.log(val, mask, color, (val & mask) >>> 0)
        if ((findColor && ((val & mask) >>> 0 == color)) || (!findColor && ((val & mask) >>> 0 != color))){
            l = r = ((i / 4) % rect.w);
            t = b = Math.floor(i / 4 / rect.w);
            break;
        }
    }

    // We found nothing.
    if (i >= data.length) {
        return null;
    }


    // Scan from bottom to first pixel
    for (var j = data.length - 4; j > i; j -= 4){
        var val = module.RGBToHex({r:data[j], g:data[j+1], b:data[j+2], a:data[j+3]});
        if ((findColor && ((val & mask) >>> 0 == color)) || (!findColor && ((val & mask) >>> 0 != color))){
            l = Math.min(l, ((j / 4) % rect.w))
            r = Math.max(r, ((j / 4) % rect.w))
            b = Math.floor(j / 4 / rect.w);
            break;
        }
    }

    console.log(l, r, t, b);

    // Scan from left
    for (var x = 0; x < l; x ++){
        for (var y = t + 1; y <= b; y ++){
            i = (y * rect.w + x) * 4
            var val = module.RGBToHex({r:data[i], g:data[i+1], b:data[i+2], a:data[i+3]});
            if ((findColor && ((val & mask) >>> 0 == color)) || (!findColor && ((val & mask) >>> 0 != color))){
                l = Math.min(l, x);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    console.log(l, r, t, b);


    // Scan from right
    for (var x = rect.w - 1; x > r; x --){
        for (var y = t; y < b; y ++){
            i = (y * rect.w + x) * 4
            var val = module.RGBToHex({r:data[i], g:data[i+1], b:data[i+2], a:data[i+3]});
            if ((findColor && ((val & mask) >>> 0 == color)) || (!findColor && ((val & mask) >>> 0 != color))){
                r = Math.max(r, x);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    console.log(l, r, t, b)

    return new module.Rect(l + rect.x, t + rect.y, (r - l), (b - t));
}
```

In this code `BitmapData` just wraps a canvas object and its context2d, and `Rect` is an `{x: , y: , w: , h: }` object. I had to do some screwing around with RGBToHex to make sure I was getting positive numbers (uint's) too:

```
module.RGBToHex = function(rgb) { 
    return (rgb.a << 24 | rgb.r<<16 | rgb.g<<8 | rgb.b) >>> 0; 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

here's my quick'n'dirty solution, maybe somebody'll find it useful ;)

```
/**
 * get a rectangle around color
 * @param  {...} ctx 2dCanvasObject to be scanned
 * @return {Object}     object storing the rectangle's data (x, y, w(idth), h(eight))
 */
function getColorBoundsRect(ctx) {
    /**
     * the canvas' context's data property (shorthand)
     * @type {...}
     */
    var data = ctx.data,
    /**
     * counter variable
     * @type {Number}
     */
        i = 0,
    /**
     * the "leftest" pixel that is not black (starts right, as we check if currently looped pixel (that is not black) is "lefter" than the current outerLeftPixel)
     * @type {Number}
     */
        outerLeftPixel = w-1,
    /**
     * the "rightest" pixel that is not black (starts left, as we check if currently looped pixel (that is not black) is "righter" than the current outerRightPixel)
     * @type {Number}
     */
        outerRightPixel = 0,
    /**
     * the "toppest" pixel that is not black (starts at bottom, as we check if currently looped pixel (that is not black) is "topper" than the current outerTopPixel)
     * @type {Number}
     */
        outerTopPixel = h-1,
    /**
     * the "bottomest" pixel that is not black (starts at top, as we check if currently looped pixel (that is not black) is "bottomer" than the current outerBottomPixel)
     * @type {Number}
     */
        outerBottomPixel = 0,
    /**
     * x coordinate of currently looped pixel
     * @type {Number}
     */
        x,
    /**
     * y coordinate of currently looped pixel
     * @type {Number}
     */
        y;

    // loop through all pixels
    // i equals the i'th pixel (0 is the upper left pixel, w*h is the bottom right pixel)
    while (i < (data.length / 4)) {
        // check if currently looped pixel is anything else than black --> color
        if ((data[i*4] + data[i*4+1] + data[i*4+2]) > 0) {
            // set coordinates for the currently looped pixel
            x = i % w; // if one row has 10px and i = 35, the x coordinate of the current pixel is 35 % 10 = 5
            y = Math.floor(i / w); // if one row has 10px and i=35, the y coordinate of the current pixel is 35/10 = 3.5 (--> rounded off = 3)

            // if the x coordinate of the current (colored) pixel is smaller than the current "leftest" pixel, set the x coordinate as new "leftest pixel"
            // same procedure for the other values
            if (x < outerLeftPixel) {
                outerLeftPixel = x;
            }
            if (x > outerRightPixel) {
                outerRightPixel = x;
            }
            if (y < outerTopPixel) {
                outerTopPixel = y;
            }
            if (y > outerBottomPixel) {
                outerBottomPixel = y;
            }
        }
        ++i;
    }

    // if there is color on the canvas, the outer[Right|Left|Bottom|Top]Pixel properties should have been updated accordingly and the following condition should be true 
    if (outerRightPixel > outerLeftPixel && outerBottomPixel > outerTopPixel) {
        return {
            x: outerLeftPixel,
            y: outerTopPixel,
            w: outerRightPixel - outerLeftPixel,
            h: outerBottomPixel - outerTopPixel
        };
    } 
    // if there is no color on the canvas, return false, as there is no rectangle
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```